# K-Means clustering in R error

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-means

I have a dataset that I have created in R. It is structured as follows:

```
> head(btc_data)
           Date btc_close eth_close vix_close gold_close DEXCHUS change
1647 2010-07-18      0.09        NA        NA         NA      NA      0
1648 2010-07-19      0.08        NA     25.97    115.730      NA     -1
1649 2010-07-20      0.07        NA     23.93    116.650      NA     -1
1650 2010-07-21      0.08        NA     25.64    115.850      NA      1
1651 2010-07-22      0.05        NA     24.63    116.863      NA     -1
1652 2010-07-23      0.06        NA     23.47    116.090      NA      1
```

I am trying to cluster the observations using k-means. However, I get the following error message:

```
> km <- kmeans(trainingDS, 3)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What does this mean? Am I prepocessing the data incorrectly? What can I do to fix it? I cant drop the NA's because out of 4500 initial observations, if i run `complete cases` I am left with only 100 observations.

Essentially I am hoping that 3 clusters will form based on the `change` column which has values of -1,0,1. I then wish to analyze the components of each cluster to find the strongest predictors for change. What other algorithms that would be most useful for doing this?

I also tried to remove all the NA values using the following code, but I still get the same error message:

```
> complete_cases <- btc_data[complete.cases(btc_data), ]
> km <- kmeans(complete_cases, 3, nstart = 20)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

> sum(!sapply(btc_data, is.finite)) 
[1] 8008
> sum(sapply(btc_data, is.nan))
[1] 0
> 
> sum(!sapply(complete_cases, is.finite)) 
[1] 0
> sum(sapply(complete_cases, is.nan))
[1] 0
```

Here is the format of the data:

```
> sapply(btc_data, class)
      Date  btc_close  eth_close  vix_close gold_close    DEXCHUS     change 
    "Date"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"   "factor"
```

Comment: `> sum(!sapply(btc_data, is.finite)) 
[1] 8008
> sum(!sapply(btc_data, is.nan))
[1] 18193`

Comment: @coffeinjunky I edited the question....also, I dont know why the `sum` for complete cases is `721` especially since there are only 103 observations...when I manually inspect the df there are no NA's

Comment: Ok- I removed the `!` and edited the question...what youre saying is that the `knn` should work on `complete_cases` but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: Ok, I added that information

Comment: Cool. In this case, the date column is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variety of reasons for getting this error message, in particular in the presence of invalid data types (NA, NaN, Inf) or dates. Let's go through them:

But first, let's check that it works with the `mtcars` dataset since I will be using it:

```
kmeans(mtcars, 3)
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 9, 7, 16
--- lengthy output omitted
```

**Likely problem 1: invalid data types**: `NA/NaN/Inf`

```
df <- mtcars
df[1,1] <- NA
kmeans(df, 3)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

df[1,1] <- Inf
kmeans(df, 3)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

df[1,1] <- NaN
kmeans(df, 3)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

You can check for these values using the following:

```
df[1:3,1] <- c(NA, Inf, NaN) # one NA, one Inf, one NaN
sum(sapply(df, is.na))
[1] 2
sum(sapply(df, is.infinite))
[1] 1
sum(sapply(df, is.nan))
[1] 1
```

To get rid of these, we can remove the corresponding observations. But note that `complete.cases` does not remove `Inf`:

```
complete_df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
sum(sapply(complete_df, is.infinite))
[1] 1
```

Instead, use e.g.

```
df[apply(sapply(df, is.finite), 1, all),]
```

You can also reassign these values or impute them, but this is a whole different procedure.

**Likely problem II: Dates:** See the following:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- mtcars
df$date <- seq.Date(from=ymd("1990-01-01"), length.out = nrow(df), by=1)
kmeans(df, 3)
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(df, 3) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

You can get around this problem by excluding the dates or by converting the dates to something else, e.g.

```
df$newdate <- seq_along(df$date)
df$date <- NULL
kmeans(df, 3)
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 9, 7, 16
---- lengthy output omitted
```

Or you can try to coerce the dates to numeric yourself before you pass it to `kmeans`:

```
df <- mtcars
df$date <- seq.Date(from=ymd("1990-01-01"), length.out = nrow(df), by=1)
df$date <- as.numeric(df$date)
kmeans(df, 3)
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 9, 16, 7
--- lengthy output omitted
```

Comment: I understand, but 2 things- the data is two small when I remove the NA's. More importantly I ran `complete_cases` and then did the `knn` but I still get the same error.

Comment: If you don't have (enough) data, there is really not that much that we can help you with. The only thing you could try is imputing your data instead of removing it. Regarding your second point, I can't comment on that since you haven't posted that code or that error message.

Answer (score 2):

Check datatype of the variable on which you are clustering. Most probably the error can come if the datatype is non-numeric. Also try handling date formats properly before you cluster.

Comment: That didn't really add anything to the existing and accepted answer from a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "Date" column in clustering?

You should use numeric type data in using k-means clustering.

try this,

> btc_data$Date = as.numeric(gsub("-", "", as.character(btc_data$Date)))

Comment: No need for `gsub/as.character`, just `as.numeric(btc_data$Date)` will do it.